# Using one list across many functions

Tags: c#

I have a class of houses (the channel enum is not displayed here)

The class has objects referenced and two constructors, and then inside the class  there is a List called 'inventory' and two or more functions that try to access the list, What I'd like to do is use this same list across all of the separate functions inside of 'class houses' 
but I am getting a 'does not exist in current context' error, Which makes me think this is a problem of scope.
But all the methods are in the same 'class houses' ... Aren't they of the same scope?

Obviously not following the right path,  How should I look at this?

```
class property
{
public string AddressNumber { get; set; }
        public string AddressStreet { get; set; }
        public double ListingPrice { get; set; }
        public double MonthlyRent { get; set; }
        public double Taxes { get; set; }
        public Channel Channel { get; set; }


        public property(string addnum, string addstreet, double lp, double mr, double taxes, Channel rorm)
        {
            AddressNumber = addnum;
            AddressStreet = addstreet;
            ListingPrice = lp;
            MonthlyRent = mr;
            Taxes = taxes;
            Channel = rorm;

        }
        public property()
        {
            AddressNumber = "4319";
            AddressStreet = "Forestview";
            ListingPrice = 600000;
            MonthlyRent = 0;
            Taxes = 2000;
            Channel = Channel.Rosa;

        }


      static  List<property> inventory = new List<property>
            {
                new property("19263","Collingham",24000,700,1744, Channel.Rosa),
                new property("16003","Collingham",24000,700,1672, Channel.Rosa),
                new property("13051","Bringard",24000,700,1305, Channel.Rosa),
                new property("10409","Bringard",24000,650,1591, Channel.Rosa),
                new property("10086","Marne",24000,650,1176, Channel.Rosa),
                new property("10042","Peerless",24000,650,1313, Channel.Rosa),
                new property("10736","Steel",30000,1000,1587, Channel.Mike),
                new property("2010","Glendale",30000,1000,1587, Channel.Mike),
                new property("2260","Blain",30000,1000,1587, Channel.Mike),
                new property("3000","Fullerton",30000,1000,1587, Channel.Mike),

            };

        property addtolist= new property("864", "Alter", 30000, 650, 1600, Channel.Rosa);
        inventory.Add(addtolist);


public static void userAddItem()
{
//I want to use the list here
}

public static void allItemsToFile()
{
//and here
}

} //end of house class bracket
```

Comment: If the list is supposed to be shared by all instances, make the list static. If it is not shared by all instances, remove the keyword static from your userAddItem and allItemsToFile methods,

Comment: i don't think the code even runs. He is doing .Add inside class definition

Comment: `inventory` should be static to be shared across all instances. Also, because it's not static, it can't be referenced in a `static` method.

Comment: If you want to use the list in your methods (which are static), you need to make your list static as well. But I'm having a bit more issues with your "Constructors" that are called "property" when your class name is "houses"?

Comment: Thanks,  I added static modifier to the naming of inventory everything runs smoothly.  The class should have been property, is it was in the IDE.  Compiles great and reading up what static is.  Thanks for the very quick review.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of your classes as objects.  So your house class can just be a object that defines a house.

```
public class houses
{
    public string AddressNumber { get; set; }
    public string AddressStreet { get; set; }
    public double ListingPrice { get; set; }
    public double MonthlyRent { get; set; }
    public double Taxes { get; set; }
    public Channel Channel { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you want to make a list of properties.  In your main class, you can do something like this;

```
private List<houses> properties = new List<houses>();

houses house1 = new houses();

house1.AddressNumber = "19263";
house1.AddressStreet = "Collingham";
house1.ListingPrice = 24000.0;
hosue1.MonthlyRent = 700.0;
house1.Taxes = 1744.0;
house1.Channel = Channel.Rosa;

properties.Add(house1);
```

Now you have a list of properties and you can access them as you need.

```
Foreach(houses h in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", h.AddressNumber, h.AddressStreet, h.ListingPrice, h.MonthlyRent, h.Taxes, h.Channel.toString());
}
```